# Autocomplete issue while typing git stash show stash@{1}

Tags: git, autocomplete

First I type `git stash show`.

Then type <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd>, and it shows `git stash show stash@{`, till now it works fine.

But after I type <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd>, it becames `git stash show stashstash@{1}`, and it is obvious wrong.

I think there may be some wrong in the following code in **.git-completion.bash**, but I can hardly read this.

```
_git_stash ()
{
    local save_opts='--keep-index --no-keep-index --quiet --patch'
    local subcommands='save list show apply clear drop pop create branch'
    local subcommand="$(__git_find_on_cmdline "$subcommands")"
    if [ -z "$subcommand" ]; then
        case "$cur" in
        --*)
            __gitcomp "$save_opts"
            ;;
        *)
            if [ -z "$(__git_find_on_cmdline "$save_opts")" ]; then
                __gitcomp "$subcommands"
            else
                COMPREPLY=()
            fi
            ;;
        esac
    else
        case "$subcommand,$cur" in
        save,--*)
            __gitcomp "$save_opts"
            ;;
        apply,--*|pop,--*)
            __gitcomp "--index --quiet"
            ;;
        show,--*|drop,--*|branch,--*)
            COMPREPLY=()
            ;;
        show,*|apply,*|drop,*|pop,*|branch,*)
            __gitcomp_nl "$(git --git-dir="$(__gitdir)" stash list \                                                               
                    | sed -n -e 's/:.*//p')"
            ;;
        *)
            COMPREPLY=()
            ;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.2.37(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin12.0.0).

git version: 1.8.0.3

whole source: https://gist.github.com/pktangyue/5477924

Comment: I'm using bash `4.1.10(1)`. I have the same completion function defined in my `/etc/bash-completion.d/git-completion.sh`, and the completion works fine on my end. Can you give details about your version of bash ? Also if you could post a link (to a gist may be ?) to your complete `git-completion.sh` it might be useful for comparing.

Comment: @Tuxdude added more info.

Comment: I gather that you have at least 10 stashes? I'm trying to replicate your situation. I do not experience this problem with two stashes (git 1.8.2.3, bash 4.2.45, Arch Linux x86_64).

Comment: Edit: actually, I cannot reproduce this even with 11 stashes. I suggest you consider upgrading your version of bash, as there don't appear to be any significant changes in git's `stash` behaviour between 1.8.0.3 and 1.8.2.3)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I manually downloaded git completion script which was outdated. I was able to fix it by getting the latest using homebrew.

```
brew install git bash-completion
```

Remove old links that you may have in your ".profile". Replace to use the script  from brew

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Now  when I tab on, it completes correctly. (git stash show stash@{0 .. gives git stash show stash@{0})

Answer (score 0):

Bash-Completion should come as a separate package more or less independent of Bash itself. For example I have bash version 4.1.10-4 and bash-completion version 1.3-1 from Cygwin and the completion you describe works as it should.

Please check what version of Bash-Completion you have installed. You could also try to install the latest version directly from http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/ or try to replace only the file `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` with the upstream version.